# HP T620 Flexible Thin Client loses all the data on the SSD after a power cycle

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, ssd, hardware-failure

I bought a refurbished HP T620 Flexible Thin Client some time ago and today I had the idea to use it headless with a TV Tuner and Tvheadend, so I began with installing Ubuntu Server on it. Everything went fine, I rebooted and checked that I have SSH access on it. I then turned it off, moved in another room and after powering it back on I saw that it doesn't come back online. I plugged in a monitor and noticed that it complains about not finding any boot medium.

I booted a live Linux environment and turns out that the entire SSD was zeroed out:

[image: whHexEditor showing 00 for the entire SSD]

It seems that the data stored on the SSD does not survive a power cycle event. I even validated this by writing a plain "Hello world" string on the SSD (`echo "Hello world" > /dev/sda`), checked with wxHexEditor that it is there, rebooted, checked again that it is there (it was), then turned off and the SSD was again entirely empty.

The SSD is a [SanDisk SDSA5DK-016G-1006](https://i.imgur.com/4PPBRaa.jpg). Am I missing something, or the SSD is just defective? I had some experiences in the past with defective SSDs, but never saw something like this happening.

Comment: Since the SSD lost everything and cannot start, it is likely defective. Get the SSD's manufacturer's disk test app on bootable USB Key and test the drive.

Comment: @John - Defective in what way exactly? If it reached its lifetime write limit then the initial installation would have failed. The screenshot suggests the device is in read only access. Thin clients typically are not used in the way the author describes. My only experience is seeing them display an application running on a server.

Comment: Thin clients typically are not used in the way the author describes.     ........  Yes. But since the author has used it this way and it is not starting it needs to be tested\

Comment: It does sound like something is defective (Ive also not seen this before).  According to the specs, that device has a volatile write cache - so I wonder if its not able to flush the cache, or the cache is working but the underlying SSD is defective?  Out of curiosity, have you done a S.M.A.R.T test on the device?

Comment: @davidgo I don't see anything worrying in the smart data: https://pastebin.com/wVcTshNZ

Comment: I found out there's an empty slot that looks like a NVME port: https://i.imgur.com/xGyPGyl.jpeg, but a NVME SSD I put there wasn't recognized. Strangely, it worked with a M.2 module with a B+M key and this time the data stored on this SSD module is not lost. I still wonder if the SanDisk one is just faulty or meant as a sort of cache.